# i can't add webapp button in "node-telegram-bot-api" to my telegram channel

Tags: javascript, api

```
createTournament=async()=>{
  const arrayButton = []
  arrayButton.push([{ text: "google.com", web_app: {url: "https://google.com"}}])

  const options = {
    reply_markup: JSON.stringify({ inline_keyboard: arrayButton }),
    parse_mode: 'HTML',
  }
  await bot.sendMessage(idChanel, 'google.com',options )  
}
```

When I send a message in private, everything is sent successfully, but when I send in a public channel, an error appears:

```
body: {
  ok: false,
  error_code: 400,
  description: 'Bad Request: BUTTON_TYPE_INVALID'
},
```

I added my bot to the channel as an administrator

when i write code `arrayButton.push([{ text: "google.com", callback_data: ...`

the message is sent and the button appears

but when i use the "web_app" option i get the above error

Answer (score 0):

Telegram bot API doesn't allow to send this type of buttons in channels, it's allowed for only private chats between a user and bot:

> Description of the Web App that will be launched when the user presses the button. The Web App will be able to send an arbitrary message on behalf of the user using the method answerWebAppQuery. **Available only in private chats between a user and the bot.**

See API reference here: https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#inlinekeyboardbutton

Comment: this is not true; try to inline call the @CallegramBot in any group (wether the bot is a member or not!) and you will be able to trigger a inline keyboard button with image and url in any chat on the article selection of the bot. HOW does this work?!